# Offline ActiveX Control for Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, activex, bho

I have a C#/.Net User Control that is a viewer for particular file type.
Now i want to convert it to an ActiveX control for the internet explorer which gets loaded when we open that file type with internet explorer and the file gets opened within the control.

It is the similar feature like Adobe PDF Reader ActiveX control. When we drag n drop a pdf file over the internet explorer, the pdf reader control is loaded and file is opened in that control.
can i use BHO in this case?

Please help me with this.
Reply if you have answer or any other solution.
Thanks in advance.